# Java Servlet Mappings

Tags: java, exception, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a servlet defined as in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SessionRebindServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.ppp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now when there is a request with extension `.ppp` it uses the above servlet.

But I want to have one exception here that if the file with name "popup.ppp" then don't call this servlet at all.

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

I added a filter

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AppFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ppp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and in filter code :

```
String url = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
        if (url.contains("popup.ppp")) {

        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
```

Comment: you can add logic in your SessionRebindServlet to ignore "popup.ppp" request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this for such cases:

```
String lPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
if (lPath.startsWith("/supported")) {
   chain.doFilter(request, response); 
} else {
  // not supported
}
```

Comment: He isn't talking about filters.

Comment: Actually that worked.

I added a filter and did what @stefan Be has said.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that with the `<url-mapping/>` element. See the [spec chapter 12](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-mrel-spec.pdf) for all options.

Can't you map to `/somepath/*.ppp` so it does not interfere with `popup.ppp` or call `popup.ppp` something else?

Answer (score 1):

By  using filter and simply override doFilter() method in filter:

String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();

then use this url and compare with popup.ppp it it not equal then doFilter()

OR

Try this(I have not checked with this)

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SessionRebindServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.ppp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>newServletName</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>popup.ppp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: He isn't talking about filters.

Comment: Yes, using filter as a work-around works of course. Thanks for clarifying your answer.